# How to click an HTML DOM element through a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make some bookmarklets to navigate through a web-application.

For some of the links and actions, they're as simple as having bookmarklets such as `javascript: tabClick('func');`, for others, if I inspect element their `href` values are void, and I only get these long links.

```
<a id="id_value" eventvalue="Do Action">Do Action</a>
```

Is there any way to have a bookmarklet that would simulate clicking <kbd>Do Action</kbd>?

Comment: document.getElementById("assetmain3_middle_anchor").click();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use JavaScript to select the element by its `id` (unique to that particular element) and send the `click` event to it, which should emulate exactly the same behavior that would occur if the user were to point and click the element.

```
javascript:document.getElementById("id_value").click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one that may work for you.

```
javascript: var x = document.getElementById(prompt('What Id?')).click();
```

Comment: The question is asking about clicking a particular HTML element. This doesn't address the question.

Comment: Whoops I didn't realize that